# How can I redirect links to an old home.asp file to a new index.php?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a website that has a lot of old, incoming links on external sites.  These links point to `http://domain.com/home.asp` .

However, the current site is built in WordPress, with `http://domain.com/` as the URL with `index.php` being in the root.

Currently, any links pointing to the `home.asp` are redirecting to a 404 Not Found.  What is the best way to redirect those links to the new `index.php`?  Is .htaccess my best bet?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/home.asp / [L,R=301]
```

should do the trick

L means stop rewriting after this line
R=301 means to send an MOVED PERMANENTLY respons to the client

Comment: Thank you!  I figured it would be something along these lines, thanks for the confirmation.